# Добавить функцию в декомпилированый *.swf файл

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe, декомпиляция

Декомпилировал *.swf файл с помощью JPEXS Free Flash Decompiler 10.0.0,

добавил функцию, сохранения строк в txt файл

Код:

```
package 
{
   ...
   import flash.filesystem.*;       //  добавил я

   public class NewSocket extends SecureSocket
   {
      ...
      {
         super();
      }

      ....

      public function send(param1:String) : void
      {
       //  добавил я
         var file : File = File.desktopDirector.resolvePath("your_file_name.txt");
         var fs : FileStream = new FileStream();
           fs.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
           fs.writeUTFBytes(param1);
           fs.close();
       //  добавил я

         ...
      }     
      ...      
   }
}
```

когда сохраняю, получаю сообщение "Not a type строка №"

это здесь

> var file : File = File.desktopDirector.resolvePath("y
>   our_file_name.txt");

проверил во flash CS6

> import flash.filesystem;

у меня такого нет

читал что должен быть adobe AIR, так он установлен

как мне подключить этот класс, что бы функция заработала

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы использовать flash.**F**ilesystem.**F**ile**S**tream в JPEXS Free Flash Decompiler, вы должны писать **заглавными буквами**.

Чтобы использовать flash.Filesystem.FileStream в Adobe Flash CS, вы должны в меню **Publish Settings** параметр **Target** выбрать **AIR**.